# How to show a variable number of mongo document fields in a spacebars template

Tags: mongodb, meteor-blaze, spacebars

Say in a MongoDB collection we have a document that contains:

- A field called "fieldnames" containing an array with a list of some 
  field names of the same document:

  ["fieldname1", "fieldname2", ... "fieldnameN"]
- The fields listed in the fieldnames field, of our interest:

  fieldname1 = "abc";

  fieldname2 = 55;

  ...

  fieldnameN = "test"
- Some more fields not of our interest here.

The number of fields of interest in the document may increase or decrease and 
a priori we don't know which can be their names, however we know that 
the "fieldnames" field always contains all of their names.

Now the problem that after reading and searching I haven't been able to figure out:

We want to show in a Spacebars template all the fields names listed in 
fieldnames, together with its corresponding field value, like 
in this pseudocode:

```
{{#each field in fieldnames}}
        {{fieldName}}    {{fieldValue}}
{{/each}}
```

The expected result would then be:

fieldname1  abc

fieldname2   55

fieldnameN  test

If I loop over the fieldnames array, then I don't know how 
  to access the values of the field names it contains.

Important: the data shown needs to be reactive.